# The type 'void' can not be assigned to the type 'ObservableInput <Action>'

Tags: angular, typescript, observable, ngrx, ngrx-store

I'm receiving the next type error when I'm trying to dispatch an observable of actions in my effect as shown below:

```
 @Effect()
    rideSummary$: Observable<Action> = this.actions$.pipe(
        ofType<GetRideSummary>(RideActionTypes.GetRideSummary),
        map(action => action.payload),
        switchMap(payload => {
            const { ride, passenger } = payload;
            const allPassengers = [...ride.passengers, passenger];
            this.store.dispatch(new SetLoading);
            return this.directionService.computeRideRouteSummary(ride, allPassengers)
            .then((summary: RideRouteSummary) => {
                const updatedRoute = Geometry.newFromData({
                    type: Geometry.LINE_STRING,
                    coordinates: summary.route
                });

                const totalTime = summary.totalTime;
                const arrivalTime = ride.type === Ride.TYPE_TOWORK ?
                    ride.hour :
                    ride.hour + summary.totalTime;
                const departureTime = ride.type === Ride.TYPE_TOWORK ?
                    ride.hour - summary.totalTime :
                    ride.hour;
               this.store.dispatch(new UnsetLoading);
               return this.store.dispatch(new GetRideSummarySuccess({
                    updatedRoute,
                    totalTime,
                    arrivalTime,
                    departureTime
                }));
                }
            ).catch(error => {
                this.store.dispatch(new UnsetLoading);
                catchError(() => of(new HandleError(error)));
            });
        })
    );
```

The type error says:

```
Unable to assign an argument of type "(payload: {ride: Ride; passenger: Passenger;}) => void" to the type parameter "(value: {ride: Ride; passenger: Passenger;}, index: number) => ObservableInput <Action> ".
The type 'void' can not be assigned to the type 'ObservableInput <Action>'.
```

I'm not sure what is the problem with the code. Seems to be something related to the `promise`. Any help?

Comment: I don't know RxJS, and it would have helped if you marked the line that the error occurred on, but in this case I have a good guess of the problem: a missing `return` before `this.directionService.computeRideRouteSummary(...)`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The effect is defined as `@Effect()` meaning it expects an `Action`.
The quick but dirty fix is to define your effect as `@Effect({dispatch: false})`.
The more proper fix is to remove all of the store dispatches in your effect and return an action.

A quick example would be:

```
switchMap(payload => {
  this.store.dispatch(new FooBar());
}
```

To:

```
switchMap(payload => {
  return new FooBar();
}
```

Comment: in this case, when I return the action there's an incompatibility returning the Action. The promise require return `void`. How can I handle this?